# Explanation for Bound of Cauchy Inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$ | \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_j | ^2 $ + $ | \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j} a_j | ^2 \leq (n+2) \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_j^2 $.

By simple expansion,  $ LHS = 2\sum \limits_{j=1}^n {a_j^2} + 4\sum \limits_{j, k \in S }^n a_j a_k$, where $S$ is the set of all $ 1 \leq j < k \leq n$ where $j+k$ is even.
Then
$4\sum \limits_{j , k \in S }^n a_j a_k \leq \sum \limits_{s=1}^n {n_s a_s^2}  $ where $n_s$  denotes the number of pairs $(j, k)$ in $S$ with $j = s$ or $ k = s$.
One has $ n_s ≤ \left \lfloor{\frac{(n − 1)}{2}}\right \rfloor  $, so substituting it into $\sum \limits_{s=1}^n {n_s a_s^2} $ obtains the solution.

Questions

1. Why did the author assumed that $j + k$ must be even?
2. An explanation of why his method had worked based on the $j + k$ condition.

Comment: You’re forgetting the signs when expanding the second term of the LHS.

Comment: Even so, how would one derive Steele's solution?

Comment: Because the signs will cancel some of the terms in the two double products (you’ll only keep those with $j+k$ even).

Comment: But would that only work if the absolute functions were not there?

Comment: No. Remember $|S|^2=S^2$.